# How to Create a lightbox Application in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, c#-3.0

I am developing a Windows application in which I want to display a pop-up form. I'd like this form to open the same way as a lightbox window does (like when using a jQuery lightbox plugin, for example). How would I go about this?

Comment: What's wrong with a `MessageBox`? Lightboxing is *incredibly* user hostile, at least if you're talking about the entire screen, and really should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @ Cody Gray: i want to display a small form not a message box but it want to pop up with some animation that is what i needed

Comment: All forms in WinForms have a `ShowDialog` method that makes them behave just like a `MessageBox`. You might investigate that built-in functionality. Animation is difficult, especially in WinForms. What type of animation are you thinking about?

Comment: i want some smooth fadein animation for popup form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the revised question

> i want some smooth fadein animation for popup form

On your dialog form set the `Opacity` equal to a low number like 10%

Add a `System.Windows.Form.Timer`. Set its `Enabled` property to `true` and its `Interval` property to `50`

For the timer tick event handler write this.

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Opacity == 1 )
        {
            this.timer1.Enabled = false;
            return;
        }

        this.Opacity+=.1;

    }
```

You can try different values of the stepping (`this.Opacity+=.1;`) and the timer's interval to find the the timing you like best.